# Finding CDF for a PMF?

Tags: probability-theory

This question is found here (#2: https://www.examsolutions.net/tutorials/exam-questions-probability-density-functions-and-cumulative-distribution-functions/)

But, in essence, the given probability that a mosquito survives for more than t days is given by: $$\frac{225}{(t+15)^2}, \quad t\ge 0$$

We're asked to show that the CDF of T is given by $$F(t) =
\begin{cases}
1-\frac{225}{(t+15)^2}  & t\ge 0 \\[2ex]
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

From my basic knowledge, taking the intergral of the PDF results in the CDF but not in this case... Why does the CDF = 1 - PDF? Is the top function a PDF at all - am I missing something? I know that if you graph the PDF, the area under the curve must be 1 but there is no bound on this function?

I'm new to the concept so I'm probably missing some key idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're given the [survival function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function)
$$
S(t)=\frac{225}{(t+15)^2} \quad\text{for }t\ge0
$$
that is 
$$
S(t)=\Bbb P\{T>t\}=1-\Bbb P\{T\le t\}=1-F(t)
$$
where $F(t)$ is the cumulative distribution function:
$$
F(t)=1-S(t)=\begin{cases}
1-\frac{225}{(t+15)^2}  & t\ge 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

That is not the pdf.

The given probability that a mosquito survives for more than $t$ days means $P(T > t)$.

Hence $$P(T \leq t) = 1-P(T > t)$$